# Python zeep problem for integrate a list of <item>

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

I've got a SOAP service who's calling like this :

```
import zeep
import random
import string
from lxml import etree as ET

class Hostopia_SOAP():

    def __init__(self, user, password, wsdl):
        self.wsdl = wsdl
        self.cred = self.set_cred(user, password)
        self.sc = zeep.Client(self.wsdl)

    def set_cred(self, user, password):

        return {'username' : user, 'password' : password}

    def get_all_domains(self, start=0, package=None, status=None, externalid=None, rserverid=None, 
            accountid=None, customernumber=None):

         return self.sc.service.getAllDomains(self.cred,str(start),[ ])
```

The xml result look like :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:getAllDomains xmlns:ns0="urn:RRAD">
      <primary>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
      </primary>
      <startNumber>0</startNumber>
      <conditions/>
    </ns0:getAllDomains>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

and all going great!

But however i'm trying to put some conditions like:

```
 self.sc.service.getAllDomains(self.cred,str(start),[ 'key1=value' ])
```

in my request i've got that error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:/No-git/Scripts/HostoSOAP.py", line 286, in <module>
    print(client.debug('getAllDomains', '0', ['status=OK']))
  File "z:/No-git/Scripts/HostoSOAP.py", line 243, in debug
    node = self.sc.create_message(self.sc.service, service, self.cred, *args)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\client.py", line 139, in create_message
    operation_name, args, kwargs, client=self
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 68, in _create
    serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
    return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 74, in serialize
    self.body.render(body, body_value)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 231, in render
    self._render_value_item(parent, value, render_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 255, in _render_value_item
    return self.type.render(node, value, None, render_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 279, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 242, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 231, in render
    self._render_value_item(parent, value, render_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 255, in _render_value_item
    return self.type.render(node, value, None, render_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 279, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\indicators.py", line 242, in render
    element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\any.py", line 126, in render
    self.validate(value, render_path)
  File "F:\dev-tools-plugin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\any.py", line 184, in validate
    raise exceptions.ValidationError("Missing element for Any")
zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element for Any
```

the XLM aspected look like :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:getAllDomains xmlns:ns0="urn:RRAD">
      <primary>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
      </primary>
      <startNumber>0</startNumber>
      <conditions>
        <item>key1=value</item>
        <item>key2=value</item>
      <conditions/>
    </ns0:getAllDomains>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

someone know how to integrate this?

if it can help, the waiting type is (ArrayOfString) with the followed info :

```
ArrayOfStrings({urn:RRAD}ArrayOfStrings(_value_1: string[], arrayType: xsd:string, offset: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}arrayCoordinate, id: xsd:ID, href: xsd:anyURI, _attr_1: {}))
```

dict :

```
{'name': 'ArrayOfStrings', '_element': <Group(<zeep.xsd.elements.indicators.Group object at 0x00000265210B5488>)>, '_attributes': [<Attribute(name='arrayType', type=<zeep.xsd.types.builtins.String object at 0x000002652083F7C8>)>, <Attribute(name='offset', type=<zeep.xsd.dynamic_types.arrayCoordinate object at 0x00000265210AF808>)>, <Attribute(name='id', type=<zeep.xsd.types.builtins.ID object at 0x00000265208494C8>)>, <Attribute(name='href', type=<zeep.xsd.types.builtins.AnyURI object at 0x000002652083FFC8>)>, <zeep.xsd.elements.any.AnyAttribute object at 0x00000265210AF248>], '_restriction': None, '_extension': None, '_extension_types': (), 'qname': <lxml.etree.QName object at 0x0000026521133DE0>, '_resolved': <zeep.xsd.dynamic_types.ArrayOfStrings object at 0x00000265210DD148>, 'is_global': True}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try calling getAllDomains method using kwargs, for example:

```
self.service.getAllDomains(self.cred, startNumber=str(start), conditions=[ 'key1=value' ])
```